# Verification of solution by $u$-substitution of $\int \frac{\ln x}{1+x^2}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, solution-verification, indefinite-integrals, substitution

I was trying to solve the integral $\int \frac{\ln x}{1+x^2}dx$.

using the sub $u=\frac{1}{x}$ which means $x= \frac{1}{u}$ and $dx=\frac{-du}{u^2}$, so the integral becomes

$$\int \frac{\ln\frac{1}{u}}{1+\frac{1}{u^2}}\frac{-du}{u^2}$$$$=\int \frac{\ln u}{1+u^2}du$$

At first, I thought that I just got back to where I started because both integrals seemed to be equally challenging. However I remembered that if I was to find the anti-derivative $F$ then $\int\frac{\ln x}{1+x^2}dx~=~F(x)~+~c$ but at the same time $\int\frac{\ln u}{1+u^2}du~=~F(u)$, and since $u=\frac{1}{x}$ then $F(u)=F(\frac{1}{x})$, which seems like a contradiction. Then, it looked like both integrals are equal but when we find the anti-derivative and substitute back to x the two integrals are no longer equal!

Comment: $F(\frac1x)=F(x),x>0$ as seen  in [this graph](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=I%2F2+%28%28Log%5B1+-+I+x%5D+-+Log%5B1+%2B+I+x%5D%29+Log%5Bx%5D+-+PolyLog%5B2%2C+-I+x%5D+%2B+PolyLog%5B2%2C+I+x%5D%29+%2C1%2F2+i+%28%28log%281+-+i%2Fx%29+-+log%281+%2B+i%2Fx%29%29+log%281%2Fx%29+-+Li_2%28-i%2Fx%29+%2B+Li_2%28i%2Fx%29%29)

Comment: Or were you perhaps asked to evaluate the definite integral over $[0, \infty)$, which can be computed without finding the antiderivative?

Comment: Travis willse yes you are right i was told to evaluate the integral over 0 to infinity and show that it is equal 0 and i saw how to do that in my textbook explanation,  but this question i posted is a thought that came to me.

Comment: any $F(x)$ that con be written as a function of the combination $x+\frac 1x$...
$$F(x)=g(x+\frac 1x)$$ will have the property $F(x)=F(1/x)$

Comment: WW3 thank you for the clarification thar helps but uf you could add more details

Comment: amWhy you edited the wuestion but the format is now ruined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no contradiction here---any antiderivative indeed satisfies the functional equation
$$F\left(\frac1x\right) = F(x),$$
but as you've observed, the substitution $u := \frac{1}{x}$ isn't particularly helpful for evaluating the indefinite integral.

Instead applying integration by parts with $v = \log x$, $dw = \frac{dx}{1 + x^2}$ gives
$$\int \frac{\log x}{1 + x^2} \,dx = \arctan x \log x - \int \frac{\arctan x}{x} \,dx,$$
and the integral on the right-hand side cannot be expressed in closed form in terms of elementary functions, but it can be evaluated using a standard power series technique, giving the general antiderivative
$$F(x) := \int \frac{\log x}{1 + x^2} \,dx = \arctan x \log x + \frac{i}{2} [\operatorname{Li}_2(ix) - \operatorname{Li}_2(-ix)] + C .$$ Despite the appearance of the imaginary constant $i$, $F(x)$ takes on real values for $x > 0$.

On the other hand, taking the limit of the functional identity shows that $$\lim_{x \searrow 0} F(x) = \lim_{x \to \infty} F(x) ,$$ giving the particular value $$\int_0^\infty \frac{\log x}{1 + x^2} \,dx = 0,$$ the computation of which is the content of the original problem o.p. mentioned in the comments. A standard power series argument gives the particular value $$\int_0^1 \frac{\log x}{1 + x^2} \,dx = -G ,$$ where $G := \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2 n + 1)^2} = 1 - \frac{1}{9} + \frac{1}{25} - \frac{1}{49} + \cdots$ is [Catalan's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_constant).

Comment: Thank you very much i appreciate the time and effort you put in this cery detailed answer that encompases even more cases and possibilities than the case i asked about!! And the fact that you give an expert answer to a silly beginner question makes it better.

Comment: Cheers, I'm glad you found it useful.